# How much memory will be required to train EfficientDet D7 for object detection?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I am planning on doing some object detection once I collect my image database and annotate the images. I'm going to use the TensorFlow 2 detection Model Zoo, as it offers a great selection of pre-trained models to fine-tune. I'm using TensorFlow 2.3.0 and Python 3.8.

The images that I will be collecting will be downsized to 1064 x 1064, to get a good size to retain resolution. I was looking at using the EfficientDet D7 1536x1536 model; the images will be padded to the max dimension to make the algorithm work. Using a batch size of 1 image for training, how much memory will be required to train this algorithm? I know it is a large algorithm that will take a lot.

I have access to the following machines:

- Machine 1: Intel i7 - 5960x 3 GHz 8 core, GPU = Nvidia GeForce GTX TITAN X, RAM = 32 GB
- Machine 2: Intel i7 - 5960x 3GHz 8 core, GPU = Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080, RAM = 64 GB

Will one of these machines be sufficient to work with this model? At this point, I plan to train without Google Colab and use the GPUs.

Comment: Just for your information, I couldn't fit D7 into Tesla V100 (32GB) even with batch size 1. Yet, I managed to run D6 with batch size 1 on the same GPU; batch size 2 also didn't work.